# jsFiddle's environment seems to be affecting my fiddle

Tags: jquery-ui, resize, jsfiddle

It sounds unlikely, but I've created this fiddle to demo it:
http://jsfiddle.net/dlchambers/rDpbh/
(Using Chrome 19.0 under Win7)

When the fiddle first loads, there's an unexpected upper bound on my vertical-resizing div.
If I change the size of the jsFiddle panel, the restriction is lifted.

Does this happen to anyone else?
If so, can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because you are setting the `containment` to parent, and since you specify no parent it becomes the `<body>` node in the result pane.  You can see this here - http://jsfiddle.net/mfsfu/1/.

If you remove `containment: 'parent'` you are not restricted - http://jsfiddle.net/mfsfu/2/.